A surface passing through two different surfaces
Suppose I have two surfaces $f_1=k_1$ and $f_2=k_2$ in 3D. Then, how do I find the equation of a surface passing through (intersecting) the two surfaces $f_1,f_2$?
Like, does $f_1-f_2=k_3$ help? But, this doesn't seem to help if both are the parallel surfaces. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Why the downvote?

What do you mean by the surface passing through the two given surfaces?

@MoisheKohan I meant intersecting the two surfaces. Edited now

You can talk about a surface intersecting the two given surfaces, not the surface (since such a surface is not unique). And the accepted answer does not work for this purpose in general, in particular, since your two initial surfaces could be disjoint.

@MoisheKohan yes, that is what my problem is. How to find at least one general class of surfaces intersecting the two surfaces, like a plane cutting the two surfaces

The difference of two surface equations represents another surface passing through their intersection curve.
In other words they are concurrent, ( if the word can still be used in this context) because the curve of intersection is common for all the three.

"Passing through" is meaningless for surfaces of zero thickness.
EDIT1:
Second degree Conicoids when intersected by planes also result in conic sections.


Thanks. This somewhat answers my question. But, suppose I have two random surfaces. How do I get a surface, say a plane for example intersecting both the surfaces. Like this is similar to conic sections

The equations should have for their difference only linear coefficients remaining i.e.,  higher degree terms should disappear. BTW, I think linear combinations $ a f1 + b f2 =0 $ also produce such concurrent surfaces, please check.

@ vidyarthi : Good doubt. When intersected by a plane, a second degree conicoid has its line of intersection also as a conic section. So a (conicoid, cone and plane) can share a common conic section intersection. After some time shall upload that image also.
